# How to disable Liferay portlet cache?

Tags: liferay

I am developing a [portlet](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/4.2/official/liferay-portlet-development-guide-4.2/onepage/#d0e84) for [Liferay Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liferay#Products).

I have disabled CSS and JavaScript caching by using these codes in portal-developer.properties file:

```
theme.css.fast.load=false
theme.images.fast.load=false
javascript.fast.load=false
javascript.log.enabled=true
layout.template.cache.enabled=false
last.modified.check=false
velocity.engine.resource.manager.cache.enabled=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.layoutcache.LayoutCacheFilter=false
```

But I don't know how to disable portlet caching.

When I update view.jsp file in my portlet directory I have to restart [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) to see changes.

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar, except when I make changes to some data, the previous data is cached until a new refresh is made.  Basically, some changes are made in the preferences of the portlet, and they do not show up until the page refreshes, instead of showing the changes on returning to the page.

Answer (score 5):

With the latest version, Liferay 6.2 you can turn on Development Mode.

## When using the Liferay IDE

1. Go to the Servers view and double click on the server

[image]

2. Select Development Mode, save the configuration, and restart the server

[image]

## When not using the Liferay IDE

1. Edit setenv.sh or setenv.bat (for Windows) in $LIFERAY_DIR/$TOMCAT_DIR/bin/
2. Add -Dexternal-properties=portal-developer.properties to the CATALINA_OPTS

**Reference:**
https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/using-developer-mode-with-themes-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-09-en

Answer (score 1):

I've had such problems with some misaligned clocks: When you edit the jsp through a network mount and your computer believes it's 10:00 while the server believes, that it's already 10:05, this is what might happen:

- You change the jsp at 10:01
- The tomcat sees it and compiles - everything works as expected, but the compiled page has a timestamp of 10:06
- You change the jsp again at 10:03
- Tomcat sees the changed timestamp and compares it with the timestamp of the compiled page: The compiled page is newer (timestamp-wise), so no compilation is done and the page doesn't reflect your update
- You get frustrated, restart tomcat, which takes 2 minutes
- You correct another error in the page, now it's timestamped 10:07
- Tomcat picks it up, compiles it...

Also, I believe to remember some "Context" configuration enabling to change jsp translation behaviour. Are you working on an unchanged liferay/tomcat bundle? Does the same happen when you're working on just one machine? Does the same thing happen when you take a new bundle, unzip and retry?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following line in doView method: 
ABCUtil.clearCache()
and also can use `<expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>` in yours portlet deployment descriptor.

Comment: @user718609 - What following line? _Welcome, but please note the [markup formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [FAQ on signatures in posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - use [your profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/718609/user718609) or your answers are likely to be marked as spam._

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution   use  `MultiVMPoolUtil.clear();`

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that tends to screw up JSP reloading is a timezone difference which causes an effect like the one Olaf Kock describes. Usually you can spot this in the log files as it will say something like "XXX has been modified in the future".

Because of these screwed up timestamps the new file won't we correctly detected and used. This can be easily solved by changing the timezone in the setenv.bat/setenv.sh file of Tomcat to an appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you restart tomcat. Simply deploy your portlet into deploy directory. It's fastest. 
And if you run the Liferay from Eclipse IDE I think the changes are picked up automatically.

Comment: Because liferay reloading is crap and often fails to work correctly (filesystem race conditions galore).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that deployment was not refeclting changes I maded to javascript source.

Create file named:

```
portal-ext.properties
```

Specifically in directory:

```
C:\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4\jboss-7.1.1\standalone\deployments\ROOT.war\WEB-INF\classes\
```

With content:

```
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter=false
```

Other Issues I had:

Shortccomings of windows filesystem not being able to accomodate long JBoss file/path namings in tmp directory.

Deployments were caching files I deleted

Builds were caching files I deleted

Lines in my bat file for build and deploy:

```
rd /q /s \liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4\jboss-7.1.1\standalone\tmp\work\jboss.web\default-host\my-portlet
rd /q /s \liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4\jboss-7.1.1\standalone\deployments\my-portlet.war
rd /q /s \liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\my-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\classes
ant.bat
```